# I seem to have explored myself into a dead end, how do I get out?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

So I was exploring inside random cargo containers and I managed to get myself into a situation that seems to be a dead end.  The walls are too tall for me to jump out even with my augmented leap ability, and there's nothing I can use to prop myself up.  What am I supposed to do in this area, is there a secret or switch I haven't noticed?

Here is my location:
[image]

Comment: Should this really be tagged with [the-missing-link]? Why not just tag it [dlc]?

Comment: @MrSmooth interesting question, maybe you should bring it up on meta?  My reasoning was 1) there'll probably be more DLCs in the future for DEHR, 2) the missing link is a rather big and substantial DLC when compared to the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a legitimate dead end.  After exploring all around the container and breaking the nearby walls, I can see that the area behind the boxes weren't meant to be accessed (there's nothing there).

In summary, don't go there or else you'll be stuck.